# Silex web test fails

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, silex

I'm trying to write a simple web test to test my silex api using phpunit but 
I keep getting this error when i try to run it..

```
1) App\Tests\BlogControllerTest::testInitialPage
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface, null given, called in C:\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\WebTestCase.php on line 63
```

This is my web test

```
<?php
namespace App\Tests;

use Silex\WebTestCase;

class BlogControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function createApplication()
    {
        require dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/src/Application.php';
    }
    public function testInitialPage()
    {
        $client  = $this->createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/Blog/1');

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk());

    }
}
```

The content of my Composer file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~2.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
        "crell/api-problem": "~1.7",
        "tobiassjosten/responsible-service-provider": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "6",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which exactly is line 63? is it the `createClient()`? Then it is like what the error says, you have to add a parameter to the function that implements `HttpKernelInterface` (or a mock)

Comment: 1) App\Tests\BlogControllerTest::testInitialPage
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface, null given, called in C:\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\WebTestCase.php on line 63

C:\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Client.php:42
C:\vendor\silex\silex\src\Silex\WebTestCase.php:63
C:\tests\CarType\CarTypeControllerTest.php:15

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/testing.html#webtestcase):

> For your `WebTestCase`, you will have to implement a createApplication method, which returns your application instance:
>
> ```
> public function createApplication()
> {
>     // app.php must return an Application instance
>     return require __DIR__.'/path/to/app.php';
> }
> ```

So here's what you need:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    return new Application();
}
```

But in the most cases it would be better to return configured application, from your bootstrap ([bootstrap example](https://github.com/sky003/silex-user/blob/master/web/index-test.php)):

```
public function createApplication()
{
    require __DIR__.'../web/index-test.php'; // path to your bootstrap file
    return $app;
}
```